# Update hash password with mongodb

Tags: mongodb, go, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I'm trying to update my user document to change the password but mongodb ignore the field password when I pass a bcrypt hashed password as `$2a$10$lnTLIgnOWuoolOkqBfzcd.0pNLFtstX20p8KJNQmKkL.6D.W7Zu0a`

If I remove the first `$` that work.

my update func

```
func (r Repo) Update(id string, updUsr interface{}) (User, error) {
    // uid work

    filter := bson.M{"_id": bson.M{"$eq": uid}, "deleted_at": nil}
    update := []bson.D{
        {primitive.E{
            Key:   "$set",
            Value: updUsr,
        }},
        {primitive.E{
            Key: "$addFields",
            Value: bson.D{primitive.E{
                Key:   "modified_at",
                Value: time.Now(),
            }},
        }},
    }

    res := r.col.FindOneAndUpdate(
        r.ctx,
        filter,
        update,
    )
    if res.Err() != nil {
        // err
    }

    // decode work

    return u, nil
}
```

my update func call

```
// doesn't work
updPwd := password{
    Password: "$2a$10$lnTLIgnOWuoolOkqBfzcd.0pNLFtstX20p8KJNQmKkL.6D.W7Zu0a",
}

// working version 
updPwd := password{
    Password: "2a$10$lnTLIgnOWuoolOkqBfzcd.0pNLFtstX20p8KJNQmKkL.6D.W7Zu0a",
}

_, err = us.Update(uid, updPwd)
if err != nil {
    // err
}
```

I don't know how to passe my hash variable to mongodb actually that just remove my password key because I proccess like password is an empty value and if I remove the first `$` sign my update is successfully.

Every review is appreciate !

Thank

Comment: post the error returned by the failed update.

Comment: @OptimusPette I don't have error just remove my key password from my document as you update password: ""

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In an update operation, a string value that begins with a dollar sign `$` is treated as a variable reference and replaced with the corresponding value.

You will likely need to use the [$literal](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/literal/index.html#literal-aggregation) operator for that string to be treated as a value instead of a variable.

Comment: Thank @Joe I just saw in documentation 5min ago ahah have a nice day